# How to reset Host Only Adapter Networking for Oracle VirtualBox VM Manager

Tags: networking, virtualbox, localhost, tcpip

My Host Only Networking stopped working, how do I reset it ?

I tried disabling and re-enabling Local Area Connection and VirtualBox Host-Only Network but VirtualBox Host-Only Network is still showing on Unidentified Network / not getting internet, making all my VM's on 10.0.3.15 and not able to communicate with one another.

Any suggestions?

Original Oracle Virtual Box VM Manager Networking Setup Instructions

1. In the VirtualBox Manager, go to your VM’s Settings.
2. Click on Network.
3. Change your settings to the following: Attached to: Host-only Adapter, Name: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter, Promiscuous Mode=Allow All, Check Cable Connected, click OK, then close this window.
4. Select File > Preferences.
5. Click Network.
6. Click the Properties button (screwdriver).  Enter the following IPv4 Address 192.168.137.1 and IPv4 Network Mask 255.255.255.0 and Click on the DHCP Server tab to make sure it is not enabled.
7. On the host machine, go the Network and Sharing Center and select Change Adapter Settings.
8. Right-click and select Properties. Click on Sharing tab.
9. Your settings should look like the following: Check Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet Connection Home Networking connection: VirtualBox Host-Only Network, Check Allow other network users to control or disable the shared Internet Connection
10. Click OK.  Click Yes on next screen.
11. Reset network connections on VMs and you should be good to go!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Blindly using `vboxnet0` as your interface name will not work for everyone, or even most people.

1. Use `ifconfig` to get a list of your network adapters.
2. On my machine it was the ethernet I wanted to restart, but yours may be wlan. The ethernet interface on my machine was `enp0s3`.
3. Use the ifconfig commands @encgoo mentioned. `sudo ifconfig enp0s3 down && sudo ifconfig enp0s3 up`. Replace `enp0s3` with your own interface name of course.

Answer (score -1):

This trick helps.

From the host machine:

```
sudo ifconfig vboxnet0 down
sudo ifconfig vboxnet0 up
```